# Drupal Commerce - Line Item 'display path' from views

Tags: 7, commerce

How is the 'display path' is built when the Cart view is rendered?
Why would it not be rendering some display path URLs?

I'm using a modified version [commerce_add_to_cart_extras](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras) module whereby I'm trying to link the line item to the product display node by customizing the `display path`. I can see it being added correctly when I inspect the `$line_item` object in save function of `CommerceLineItemEntityController`. But the line items in my cart still aren't linked and when I output the display path as a field in the view, it's empty.

If it would help, I can add the debug print I captured via devel's `dd()` function of the `$line_item` or my code but they will make the post rather long so I've left them out for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was my mistake.  I thought the `display_path` was being populated and I was wondering why the line items in the cart were not being linked.  But it turns out the display path is incomplete in the line item.  Here's a comparison of the `$line_item` as saved via commerce core's add to cart form:

```
stdClass Object (
    [type] => product
    [order_id] => 7
    [quantity] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [context] => Array
                (
                    [product_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4369
                        )

                    [add_to_cart_combine] => 1
                    [display_path] => node/1839
                    [entity] => Array
                        (
                            [entity_type] => node
                            [entity_id] => 1839
                            [product_reference_field_name] => field_product_reference
                        )

                )

        ) 
...
    [commerce_display_path] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => node/1839
                        )

                )

        ) 
...
```

vs.  the commerce_add_to_cart_extras `$line_item` object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => product
    [order_id] => 12
    [quantity] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [context] => Array
                (
                    [product_ids] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4375
                        )

                    [add_to_cart_combine] => 1
                    [display_path] => node/1845  //<--I modified to try and link to the display node
                    [view] => Array
                        (
                            [view_name] => products_by_category
                            [display_name] => page
                            [human_name] => Products by Category
                            [page] =>
                        )

                )
...

    [commerce_display_path] => Array
        (
            [und] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [value] =>  // <--Turns out this is empty. Now, to figure out why/where to populate this...
                        )

                )

        )
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the view, click the "Quantity input field", are you sure the "Link products added to the cart from this View to this View's path if displayed as a page." checkbox is checked? That's what makes it populate the display path.

Comment: The display path _is_ being populated, or at least I can see the display path populated when the `$line_item` is saved, but the links still aren't being rendered in the cart.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer your question.  Yes, the checkbox is also checked in the View settings.